# Which is right package name for my Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, package-name

I need package name of my Flutter app to use Firebase.

And to my knowledge, package name is something like this: `com.companyname.appname`, but inside my android > app > build.gradle, application Id is: `com.companyname.myapp.my_app`.

Which one is right one as my package name?

Comment: you can use any after ward you can change as u like.

Answer (score 1):

To see which package name your app will be built with check the build.gradle that is under /android/app/ not under /android/

You can set the packagename to whatever you want in the default config section

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.company.appname"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
}
```